# How can I pass (optional) parameters directly from CloudFormation template to CDK resource during CfnInclude without hardcoding the parameter list?

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Kind of new to these syntax, so not sure if it's achieve-able.

So we have a bunch of CloudFormation template written and we'd like to deploy them via CDK so we write code to construct them using `CfnInclude`. The problem is `CfnInclude` always require explicit `parameters` argument if there are parameters.

Is there a way to write these in a generic way, so we can create a whole bunch of resources via `CfnInclude` in just one for loop for all the CF templates, each may or may not have Parameters and the number and content of parameters is different? Cos otherwise, I'll have to supply all possible Parameters to all CF templates and then write them all out during `CfnInclude`.

The actual parameters' value are derived from another place and say then are put in a map, so say we know in total these CF templates may need 0, 1, 2 or 3 possible parameters from below list:

```
        let cfnParameters = {
            "param1": value1,
            "param2": value2,
            "param3": value3,
        };
```

Then can we somehow by supplying the template files themselves, write CDK in a way that it figures out how many and what parameters each file has, and then substitute them with proper values by looking up from the map (so that basically I'm passing a dynamically constructed `Parameters` list for each different template)? It seems like all those `getParameters` API only operate on the already constructed CF template as an object after `CfnInclude` is already called?

And I don't think we can first construct a `CfnInclude` without passing `Parameters` argument and then do `GetParameters` and somehow replace them with actual values right? Doc seems to say [Parameter Replacement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/cloudformation-include-readme.html#parameter-replacement) can only be done at construction time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `CfnInclude` needs the right keys in the [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.cloudformation_include.CfnInclude.html#parameters) prop, or will throw an error.  No problem.  Make the template's parameter replacement map *before* constructing `CfnInclude`, using language features.  Read the template file. Create a map of the template's keys and the desired values. Pass the resulting map to `CfnInclude`.

```js
// MyTemplateIncluder.ts

// values we want to apply
const parameters = {
  InstanceType: 'm1.large',
  KeyName: 'my-key-name',
  SSHLocation: '0.0.0.0/0',
  AnotherKey: 'anotherValue',
};

// read the template
const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, 'template.json');
const file = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf-8');
const templateParams = JSON.parse(file)?.['Parameters'] ?? {};

// new object with keys from the template and values from parameters
const replacementParameters = Object.keys(templateParams).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = parameters[curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

new include.CfnInclude(this, 'MyTemplate', {
  templateFile: templatePath,
  parameters: replacementParameters,
});
```

Encapsulate this logic in a reusable `Construct` subclass. Accept parameter values and the template filename as props.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah force parsing json just as json itself is definitely a way lol! Sounds like this may be the only way! Appreciate that.